# Create a new instance of a generic type at runtime without type checking

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface, solid-principles

The following design is simply a template to show my problem.

```
public interface IHero
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Level { get; }
}
public interface IWarlock : IHero
{
    string MagicType { get; }
}
public interface IKnight : IHero
{
    string CommandHierarchy { get; } 
}
public class Warlock : IWarlock, IHero
{

    string IWarlock.MagicType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    string IHero.Name { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    int IHero.Level { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public Warlock(string name, int level, string magicType)
    {

    }
}
public class Knight : IKnight, IHero
{

    string IKnight.CommandHierarchy { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    string IHero.Name { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    int IHero.Level { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public Knight(string name, int level, string commandHierarchy)
    {

    }
}
public class NullHero : IHero
{

    public string Name { get { return string.Empty } }

    public int Level { get { return -1; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
    //Increments the hero's level.
    static IHero LevelUp(IHero hero)
    {
        if (hero is IWarlock)
            return new Warlock(hero.Name, hero.Level + 1, (hero as IWarlock).MagicType);
        else if (hero is IKnight)
            return new Knight(hero.Name, hero.Level + 1, (hero as IKnight).CommandHierarchy);
        else
            return new NullHero();
    }
}
```

The problem is that next time I add a new hero, I would have to add another if statement in the LevelUp function and this becomes messy.

I know I can use Activator.CreateInstance to create a new instance however there are two problems, 1. all objects are immutable. 2. number and type of parameters in the constructor.

Could anyone please suggest a solution to this problem?

EDIT:
Yes, everyone in the comments section is correct. I can add LevelUp as a definition in the IHero interface.

Maybe I chose the wrong concept to convey my problem but let's assume that I wanted to handle LevelUp outside as shown in the template. Is there a way to tackle my only problem which is to create a new instance of type IHero without having to do type checking?

Comment: why not put a definition of LevelUp in IHero? Any implementation would then simply return `this` (granted I would question whether you really need to return anything there).

Comment: I think you should have a class that implements IHero and both of your hero should inherit that class. Right now you will be redifining heros in every new sub hero type. but they all have the same properties (name and level) that iguess will do the same stuff. Also your level up function seems strange since you give the whole hero and it return a hero back. Make a method in IHero like "LevelUp()" and do it from there.

Comment: @pijemcolu Yes, in this case I could. Because it makes sense having LevelUp as a definition in IHero. But like I said this is simply a simple template. My business logic is far more complex (which I cannot reveal) but the problem is the same. Maybe what I'm asking for is not doable but I needed to confirm it with the community.

Comment: Everything's doable, there's a sanity cost though. Did you have a look at generics? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx . Your LevelUp would look as `static T LevelUp<T>(T hero) where T : IHero { ... hero.Level++; ...}`

Comment: @pijemcolu what you are suggesting is no different from what I showed in the template. I could have simply done Level++ but I like to keep my objects immutable therefore Level++ wont work. They can only be modified by returning a new instance of the object.

Comment: Fair enough I somehow ignored the immutable part. You could try some kind of a `Clone()`/`Copy()` method definition within the `IHero`. That would avoid you the switch I guess.

Comment: I'll explore that idea and see how it turns out. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your objects are immutable and you want to keep your level up logic in the specific classes for each hero you would be best to add the LevelUp method to the IHero interface.

```
public interface IHero
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Level { get; }
    IHero LevelUp();
}
```

And in your specific hero classes you would implement the LevelUp method like so.

```
public IHero LevelUp()
{
    return new Warlock(this.Name, this.Level + 1, this.MagicType);
}
```

And you can keep your static leveup function for backwards compatibility, but you should refactor it away.

```
static IHero LevelUp(IHero hero)
{
    return hero.LevelUp();
}
```

Comment: Guess you could always serialize the object into binary and deserialize it and then increment the level... That would create you new instance of the object no matter what type it is.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that.